# Query FlexLM server to get the feature usage limit for a user

Tags: flexlm

The FlexLM (or FlexNet) server can be configured with following option:

MAX num_lic feature[:keyword=value] type {list | group_name}

The standard command (lmutil lmstat -f ) gives only the number of available licenses and the users that are using them.

Using lmutil is there a way to know how many maximum licenses can be used by a particular user ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation and my experience the answer is 'no'. You can only see the usable increments associated with a user if the `RESERVE' option is used. Then the increments are seen like used, even if the user don't use it.

For a group (I have not example with `USER`), you can have something like :

```
Users of a-increment:  (Total of 188 licenses issued;  Total of 160 licenses in use)

  "a-increment" v2015.1231, vendor: daemon-vendor
  floating license

  4 RESERVATIONs for GROUP A-GROUP_Group (license-server/27000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if you would receive better results when using: "lmutil" lmstat -a -c @ -i

We at OpenLM (www.openlm.com) use this to monitor reserved licenses.